# Auto-Prefixing Comment Lines With " *" in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When creating a comment block for a function specification in other IDEs (i.e. JetBrains), when you type "/*" and then create a newline, the IDE prefixes each new line of the block with " *". Is there a way to enable this functionality in VSCode?

Comment: What language are you working in? This should work in JavaScript and TypeScript files out of the box

Comment: I'm working in C. I'm figuring there is a plugin that enables this, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the comment with `/**`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> will break a new line start with a `*`.

Comment: @mark , I test it without extensoin `vscode --disable-extensions`, and find it work's in javascript, but not in C.

Comment: In the comments, he says he is working in C.  And Matt says it already works in Javascript out of the box.